# problem with getting the value of a textarea in spring framework, web-flow

Tags: jsf, spring-webflow

I'm a newbie in Spring MVC Framework, and the spring web flows.
I just wanna define a textfield, get the value and store it in the database. 
Here is what I got:

in "myflow.xml" file first I've definned 


`<var name="varName" class="java.lang.String"/>`

then in an action state

    `<action-state id="someFlowId">
        <evaluate expression="someEJBService.doTheStaff(varName)"/>
        <transition to="anotherFlow"/>
    </action-state>`

finally In the "myPage.xhtml" file I got 


    `<h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <injsf:inputtextarea id="richText_varName" label="MyLabel" rows="1" size="50" required="true" value="#{varName}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>`

there I also have the implementation of the java file, but 
when I run the application, I can not see the value I've entered to the textarea, in debugging, the varName value is just ""

what sholud be the reason, thanks for your help.

Comment: what is `<injsf:inputtextarea>`  ?

Comment: it's a textarea component and works well

Comment: from which library? It appears it does not work well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Bozho, your comment let me think different :)

from the `<injsf:textarea>` component I was supposed to get the value with `entityValue`, not just `value`

```
<injsf:inputtextarea id="richText_aciklama" label="#{lbl.label.gnl.aciklama}" rows="1" size="50" required="true" entityValue="#{fh.aciklama}"/>
```